# Solving Schrodinger for harmonic oscillator(griffiths analytic method)

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I was just getting into quantum mechanics. But I'm having a bit of trouble following Griffiths for the analytic method. It goes like so:

The Schrodinger equation is:

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi}{d x^2} + \frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 x^2 \psi = E \psi $$

Griffiths expresses $\xi$ as:

$$\xi = \sqrt{\frac{m \omega}{\hbar}}x$$

and $K$ as:

$$K=\frac{2E}{\hbar \omega}$$

Ultimately, leading to the equation:

$$\frac{d^2\psi}{d\xi^2}=(\xi^2-K) \psi$$

I've tried to rearrange on my own, but:

1. I do not understand why $\xi$ equals the square root, except for $x$.  $\xi$ is eventually squared.

Comment: It's just done to non-dimensionalize the equation. It's annoying keeping track of the constants when trying to solve this ODE. Instead we non-dimensionalize, solve that ODE and then put the units back in at the end.

Comment: as Cameron Williams points out, this is done for convenience. You could just as well not do it and suffer through the next couple pages in Griffith's QM with constants galore...

Comment: @Dustin incidentally, be sure to look at some of the related Q and As such as: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87655/regarding-ladder-operators-and-quantum-harmonic-oscillators?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

This follows from non-dimensionalisation or scaling - the removal of units from an equation involving physical quantities. In the case of the wavefunction, this is done through the following substitution:

\begin{equation}
    x = x_{c} \tilde{x}\\
    \frac{d}{dx} =  \frac{d\tilde{x}}{dx} \frac{d}{d\tilde{x}} = \frac{1}{x_c} \frac{d}{d\tilde{x}}
\end{equation}

where $x_{c}$ is an intrinsic characteristic unit (length) of the system and $\tilde{x}$ is the nondimensionalized counterpart of $x$. Additionally, $\psi(x) = \psi( x_{c} \tilde{x} ) = \tilde{\psi}(\tilde{x})$. After a substitution the Schrödinger equation becomes:

\begin{equation}
 \left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{1}{x_c^2}\frac{d^2}{d\tilde{x}^2} + m\omega^2 x_{c}^{2} \tilde{x}^{2} \right) \tilde{\psi}(\tilde{x}) = E \tilde{\psi}(\tilde{x})
\end{equation}

After dividing by the coefficients in front of the largest term, we get:

\begin{equation}
 \left(-\frac{d^2}{d\tilde{x}^2} + \frac{m^{2} \omega^{2} x_{c}^{4}}{\hbar^2} \tilde{x}^{2} \right) \tilde{\psi}(\tilde{x}) = \frac{2mE x_{c}^{2}}{\hbar^2} \tilde{x}^{2} \tilde{\psi}(\tilde{x})
\end{equation}

To make the terms dimensionless we equate the coefficients to unity:

\begin{equation}
 \frac{m^{2} \omega^{2} x_{c}^{4}}{\hbar^2} = 1 \implies  x_c = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{m\omega}}\\
 \frac{2mE x_{c}^{2}}{\hbar^2} =  \frac{2mE \hbar}{\hbar^2 \omega} = 1\implies E= \frac{\hbar \omega}{2} \tilde{E} 
\end{equation}

From the above equations we find that the characteristic units of energy and length of the Harmonic oscillator are, $\hbar \omega$ and $\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{m \omega}}$ , respectively. The unit free version of the time-independent Schrödinger equation for the quantum harmonic oscillator becomes:

\begin{equation}
 \left(-\frac{d^2}{d\tilde{x}^2} + \tilde{x}^2\right) \tilde{\psi}(\tilde{x}) = \tilde{E} \tilde{\psi}(\tilde{x}) \text{ or } \frac{d^2}{d\tilde{x}^2} = (\tilde{x}^2 - \tilde{E}) \tilde{\psi}(\tilde{x}) 
\end{equation}