# Closure of an Operator in $l^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $l^2$ denote the Hilbert space of all complex sequences $\phi = (\phi_j)_{j=0}^{\infty}$ such that $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} |\phi_j|^2 < \infty$. Consider the linear subspace of $l^2$ defined by
\begin{equation}
D = \{ \phi \in l^2 : \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} j^2 |\phi_j|^2 < \infty \},
\end{equation}
and let $A$ be the operator with domain $D$ which associates to each $\phi \in D$ the vector $A \phi$ whose j-th component (j=0,1,2,...) is
\begin{equation}
(A \phi)_j = \phi_{j+2} \sqrt{(j+2)(j+1)} - \phi_j - \phi_{j-2}\sqrt{j(j-1)},
\end{equation}
where we have set $\phi_{-1}=\phi_{-2}=0$. $A$ is not a closed operator. To see this, consider the vector $\phi$ with components given by
\begin{equation}
\phi_j = (-1)^{\lfloor j/2 \rfloor} j^{-\beta},
\end{equation}
with $1 < \beta < 3/2$. It is not difficult to see that $\phi \in l^2 \backslash D$, that the sequence $\xi = (\xi_j)_{j=0}^{\infty}$ defined by
\begin{equation}
\xi_j = \phi_{j+2} \sqrt{(j+2)(j+1)} - \phi_j - \phi_{j-2}\sqrt{j(j-1)},
\end{equation}
belongs to $l^2$, and that if $\phi^{(n)}$ is the vector whose first $n$ components are equal to those of $\phi$ and all the remaining components are zero, then $A \phi^{(n)}$ converges to $\xi$. So $\phi$ belong to the domain of closure of $A$, but not to $D$. 
I conjectured that the domain of the closure of $A$ is the linear subspace 
defined by (again I mean $\phi_{-1}= \phi_{-2}=0$)
\begin{equation}
S = \{ \phi \in l^2 : \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} |\phi_{j+2} \sqrt{(j+2)(j+1)} - \phi_j - \phi_{j-2}\sqrt{j(j-1)}|^2 < \infty \}.
\end{equation}
Do you have any idea of how this fact could be proved?
Thank you very much for your attention in advance.

Comment: $A$ looks like a sum of products of [these ladder operators](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87655/regarding-ladder-operators-and-quantum-harmonic-oscillators?rq=1).

Comment: For sure it has. I met this operator in a course about mathematical methods of physics. Anyway, my question is purely mathematical. Since theory of operator is new for me, I do not have a sharp intuition about these objects, and cannot even assess the degree of difficulty of my question. Maybe it has a plain answer, or maybe one would need some deeper knowledge of operator theory to answer it. I simply don't know.

Comment: Is $i(A+1)$ a symmetric operator? Symmetric operators are closable.

Comment: @Keith McClary: Clearly $A$ is closable. My question asks whether the characterization I conjectured for the closure is correct.

Comment: If it is symmetric then, by Nelson's analytic vector theorem, it is essentially self-adjoint on the finite component vectors. It follows that the closure of A restricted to that domain is the same as the closure of A (with domain D).

Comment: As I understand it, you have made a conjecture about the closure of $a^*a^* - aa$. We could make the corresponding conjecture about $a^* + a$. This is equivalent to multiplication by $x$ on the span of Hermite functions. We can characterize the closure there and then check whether it agrees with the conjecture.

Comment: @Keith McClary: For sure, with $a$ and $a*$ you meant the annihilation and creation operator quoted in the second answer to my [post] (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629025/adjoint-of-an-operator-in-l2/1629234#1629234), in which I also made the corresponding conjecture about $X=a + a*$, and as you said in a comment there, the answer is affirmative also in that case. So why should we use Hermite functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$i(A+1)$ is a symmetric tri-diagonal matrix on each of the subspaces spanned by the even and odd coordinates. These are equivalent to Jacobi matrices (real symmetric with positive off-diagonal elements). It is a [classical result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1410755/252672) that these define essentially self-adjoint operators if the off-diagonal elements grow no more rapidly than $n$.

By Theorem 2.7 of Barry Simon's [The Classical Moment Problem as a Self-Adjoint
Finite Difference Operator](http://math.caltech.edu/papers/bsimon/p269.pdf#page=21), the conjecture characterizes $D(A^*)$, which is the same as the closure of $A$ if $i(A+1)$ is essentially self-adjoint.

Comment: We have \begin{equation} S = \{ \phi \in l^2 : \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} |\phi_{j+2} \sqrt{(j+2)(j+1)} - \phi_j - \phi_{j-2}\sqrt{j(j-1)}|^2 < \infty \} =  \{ \phi \in l^2 : \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} |\phi_{j+2} \sqrt{(j+2)(j+1)} - \phi_{j-2}\sqrt{j(j-1)}|^2 < \infty \} \end{equation} so that, by the same argument in your answer to my previous question <http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629025/adjoint-of-an-operator-in-l2/1629234#1629234>, it is easy to see that $S$ is the domain of the adjoint of $i(A+1)$. If $i(A+1)$ is essentially self-adjoint, my conjecture is then true.

Comment: So the question becomes: is $i(A+1)$ essentially self-adjoint? Unfortunately, I am not familiar with matrix representations and analytic vectors, so I can't check the conditions you quoted.

Comment: You don't need to know about analytic vectors. The simple proof in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1410755/252672) shows that if $\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{b_n} = \infty$ then there is no $l^2$ sequence orthogonal to the range of $A-\lambda$ for non-real $\lambda$  where $A$ is a Jacobi matrix (not the same as your $A$) and $b_n$ are the off-diagonal elements.

Comment: Oops, the Jacobi matrix is called $J$, not $A$.

Comment: After a little bit of thinking  I have succeeded in understanding the argument you gave in the answer you quoted (a proof can also be found in Schmudgen, Unbounded Self-Adjoint Operators on Hilber Space, Example 7.6), which in turn implies (see Schmudgen, Unbounded Self-Adjoint Operators on Hilber Space, Proposition 3.8) that the restriction of $i(A+1)$ to the space of finite linear combinations of even (odd) coordinates is essentially self-adjoint.

Comment: We conclude that $i(A+1)$ is essentially self-adjoint on $D$ (see my last comment in my other my [post] (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629025/adjoint-of-an-operator-in-l2/1629234#1629234>) ), and this proves my conjecture.

Comment: By the way, I made a slip in my comment above, where I quoted the answer to my other post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629025 to Keith McClary, but it was actually given by TrialAndError.